# Binary to Decimal converter

Tags: python, binary, decimal, data-conversion

I'm trying to create a binary to decimal converter. I'm not allowed to use int() and/or bin() to convert between # systems.

I've spent a solid 12 hours and I don't think I'm getting anywhere, I'm a complete newbie at this, any help at all would be great. What I'm trying to do is take user input as a string, and reverse it so I can multiply it by 2^(string length)

```
index = 0
total = 0
binary_number = str(input("please input a number")) 
print("input test: ", binary_number) #test line
size = len(binary_number) - 1
print(size) #determine string length
binary_number = binary_number[::-1]
print("reversed: ", binary_number) #test line


while index < size:
    for a in range(len(binary_number)):
        if binary_number[index] == '1':
            total = binary_number * 2**[index]
            index += 1
        else:
            total = total
            index +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some silly mistakes.

**1.** For a string of length 'L', valid index range is from 0 to (L-1).

In your while loop, you have written " index < size ". This would have been perfect, if you had not decreased size by 1 with this line,
size = len(binary_number) - 1

**2.** Incorrect logic to convert a binary string to decimal number

This line in the while loop "for a in range(len(binary_number)): " is completely wrong. You do not need this.

**3.** Whenever you find a '1' in you binary string, you should add 2**index to the total of what you have got. But,instead, you assign "total" to a new value.

The new value that you calculate is also wrong.

You calculate it as -> binary_number * 2**[index]

Remember, binary_number is a list. [index] is also a list. You are completely messing up here. You want to do 1 * 2**index. You should remove the square brackets around index. You can put round brackets instead (). Also, instead of binary_number you should replace it by - int(binary_number[index]). Or, you don't need it.

Here is your code with minimal changes and a print statement-

```
index = 0
total = 0
binary_number = str(input("please input a number")) 
print("input test: ", binary_number) #test line
size = len(binary_number) - 1
print(size) #determine string length
binary_number = binary_number[::-1]
print("reversed: ", binary_number) #test line


while index <= size:
        if binary_number[index] == '1':
            total +=  (2**index)
            index += 1
        else:
            total = total
            index +=1
print(total)
```

Comment: thanks for the breakdown. I know there's some silly mistakes in there, it's more that coding is incredibly new to me, and I have to learn somehow.  Thankyou for your input, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class BtoD {

    public static int power(int base,int exp){
        int prod=1;
        while(exp>=0){
            if(exp==0)
                 prod=prod*1;
            else{
                prod=prod*base;
            }
            exp--;  
        }
        return prod;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String input=sc.next();
        String s[]=input.split("");
        int n=s.length;
        int decsum=0;
        int bin[]=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            bin[i]=Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
        }
        int k=0;
       for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
          decsum=decsum+bin[i]*power(2,k);
          k++;
       }
      System.out.println(decsum);

    }
}
```